# What's wrong with this return?

Tags: java

I'm new to not using a main method and i started leet coding in java and they give you the boilerplate code in a particular format. my logic is fine, but for some reason im not returning the proper string. can you guys help me on this one?

```
class Solution {
    public String defangIPaddr(String address) {
        char[] newChar = new char[address.length()];
        address.getChars(0, address.length(), newChar, 0);

        for(int i = 0; i < address.length();i++) {
            if(newChar[i] == '.') {
                return "[.]";
            }else
                return Character.toString(newChar[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

For a given input `1.1.1.1` I want as output `1[.]1[.]1[.]1`.

Comment: You'll need to define what you mean by a "proper string". By the way, your loop will only do one iteration since it will return regardless of the value of `newChar[i]` on the first iteration. So it's not clear what you're really trying to do. I assume you are using a loop for a reason.

Comment: Show us the tests, so we can read what are the provided inputs and what are the expected outputs.

Comment: Your current code: If the address contains a '.' as the first character return "[.]" otherwise return the first character as a `String` - so, what did you **want** your code to do?

Comment: "my logic is fine, but for some reason im not returning the proper string." <-- that probably means your logic is not fine.

Comment: Input: address = "1.1.1.1"
Output: "1[.]1[.]1[.]1" if the char at that index == . return [.] else return the number from the string

Comment: That code **does not compile**, because you're missing a `return` statement. Ask yourself what the return value is if `address` is an empty string.

Comment: *FYI:* The first two lines are better written as `char[] newChar = address.toCharArray()`

Answer (score 3):

Based on the clarification in comments, instead of trying to replace each dot separately, use `String#replaceAll` method to replace them all at once.

```
String address = "1.1.1.1";
address = address.replaceAll("\\.", "[.]"); //replace all dots
System.out.println(address); //prints 1[.]1[.]1[.]1
```

If you insist of doing the replacement yourself though, instead of messing with a bunch of indices, simply try to recreate the string from the start, appending each character to a `StringBuilder`, but if it is a dot append `[.]`

```
String address = "1.1.1.1";
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
for (char c : address.toCharArray()) {
    if (c == '.')
        sb.append("[.]");
    else
        sb.append(c);
}
address = sb.toString();
System.out.println(address); //prints 1[.]1[.]1[.]1
```

Comment: @AaronDavidge As i see you are a new user. Take some time and read [What should i do when someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

The logic is not good because it seems like you are returning the first character of the input string only. You can use a string builder for your solution or just a new string you will appending to. Sample:

```java
class Solution {
    public String defangIPaddr(String address) {
        char[] newChar = new char[address.length()];
        address.getChars(0, address.length(), newChar, 0);

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 0; i < address.length();i++) {
            if(newChar[i] == '.') {
                sb.append("[.]"); //append to the string builder
            }else
                sb.append(Character.toString(newChar[i]));
        }

        return sb.toString(); //return the string then
    }
}
```

I hope this may help. Good luck.